# Query Laravel Result Set

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am looking to do several queries using eloquent which are all to be returned to a single view and was wondering if there was a better way to do it than querying the database multiple times?

For example returning all the records then pulling sub sets of data from that?

At the moment I have something similar to:

```
$one = User::queryOne();
$two = User::queryTwo();
$three = User::queryThree();
```

etc

However I was thinking it would be better if it was possible to do something like:

```
$users = User::all();

$one = $users->where('created_at')...
$two = $users->where('modified_at')..
```

Obviously the above doesn't work but it it possible to do something like this?

Or is it best just to query the database separately each time?

Answer (score 1):

From a pragmatic point of view, it's 'better' to do multiple queries, because it takes you less time to write them, and they are easier to read and debug. If you want to do it with one DB query, and then grabbing subsets out of them, you'd have to write your own convoluted logic, or perhaps a new Laravel collection class. And then someone else comes along and wonders, "What is going on in this code?"

Typically programmer time is the most constrained resource in a project. When you get done, if you find that the multiple database queries are a bottleneck, then think about re-writing it.

If you do decide to do one query, you can probably order the data by the fields you want for the criteria. Then loop through the result set, adding the rows to a new array each time the specified field's value changes. That's the simplest logic I can think of offhand.

Answer (score 1):

What version of laravel are you using? In 5.1 you can do where on collections [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-where). In 4.2 you can do so with callbacks [here](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_filter)

EDIT
for 4.2 try something similar to this

```
$users = User::all();
$one = $users->filter(function($user)
{
    if($user->age > 20){
        return true;
    }
    return false;

});
```

Comment: I'm using version 4.2

Comment: Check my edit, see if that helps you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Eloquent returns a `Collection` as a result.
You could use a `foreach` statement or use the build in [Collections functions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections#available-methods) you could manipulate the results and create the sub-results.

For example you could use `filter` and do something like this:

```
$users = User::all();
$one = $collection->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->created_at >= time() - (24*60*60); // created the last day
});

$filtered->all();
```

Whether it is the best method depends on the application and the amount of data you are trying to fetch/process.

If you have only a few records from `::all()`, then doing so might be a good approach (although using the collections functions you have to run three filters across your data).

If you have a lot of records from `::all()` then it is preferably to use three different queries to the database (especially if the results will only be a few records).